# IMWheel high CPU usage / freezing with Chromium based browsers on Amazon.com

Tags: mouse, google-chrome, chromium, amazon

IMWheel works great except lately on any Chromium based browsers on Amazon. If I open a product page and scroll with the mouse wheel, the CPU's spike to 100% and the tab crashes or very slowly loads the page after about 30 seconds. Same behavior with Chromium, Chrome and Opera. Firefox works fine.

I run it with this (removing --focus doesn't fix this)

```
imwheel --focus --buttons "4 5"
```

.imwheelrc

```
"^google-chrome$"
None,      Up,   Button4, 3
None,      Down, Button5, 3
Control_L, Up,   Control_L|Button4
Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
Shift_L,   Up,   Shift_L|Button4
Shift_L,   Down, Shift_L|Button5

"^chromium-browser$"
None,      Up,   Button4, 3
None,      Down, Button5, 3
Control_L, Up,   Control_L|Button4
Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
Shift_L,   Up,   Shift_L|Button4
Shift_L,   Down, Shift_L|Button5

"^Opera$"
None,      Up,   Button4, 3
None,      Down, Button5, 3
Control_L, Up,   Control_L|Button4
Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
Shift_L,   Up,   Shift_L|Button4
Shift_L,   Down, Shift_L|Button5

"^Navigator$"
None,      Up,   Button4, 3
None,      Down, Button5, 3
Control_L, Up,   Control_L|Button4
Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
Shift_L,   Up,   Shift_L|Button4
Shift_L,   Down, Shift_L|Button5
```

Chrome 90.0.4430.212 / Opera 76.0.4017.123 / Firefox 88 / Ubuntu 20.04

Tested with both Logitech G203 & M705 Mice

Would like to figure this out so I don't have to use multiple browsers. I tried 3 scroll-wheel extensions in Chrome and found that all work well but not on 100% of websites.

Edit: This is resolved for me on Chrome Version 92.0.4515.107. I likey received some Ubuntu updates as well. Still get CPU spikes with imwheel but I think that is normal. Amazon works for me again.

Comment: This is still happening, and in Arch Linux as well. I've resolved to find a more elegant solution to the scrolling problem than IMWheel can provide.